# Range Touch Attacks, and Path of War Maneuvers?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, path-of-war

Using Adamant Entertainment's Warlock class School Ability - Arcane Bolt, a ranged touch attack.

> **Arcane Bolt (Su):** You can make a ranged touch attack that does 1d6 points of damage, +1d6 for every two warlock levels. The warlock may choose whether the damage is acid, cold, electricity, or fire. The range on an Arcane Bolt is 100ft. + 10ft./level.

Can it be used with interchangeably between melee and ranged attack maneuvers with the Path of War rules or is it strictly a ranged attack? If ranged only do I still need Point-Blank Shot and Precise Shot and Defensive Shot/Casting vs AOOs?

Answer (score 10):

### It Cannot Be Combined With Maneuvers

Pathfinder rules place unlisted actions for supernatural abilities (that is, all that don't have a listed action and are also not passive) as a standard action. You can't make the standard action to cast your Arcane Bolt and also make the standard action to initiate a maneuver; further, the Arcane Bolt is not a weapon you are wielding, and thus further cannot be used with maneuvers.

### Like all ranged touch attacks, it follows standard ranged attack rules

Among other things, that means you'll provoke an AoO for making a ranged attack in melee, that you need Precise Shot to obviate the applicable penalties, etc. Because it's not actually a weapon, certain ranged attack feats - such as Rapid Shot - are not applicable.

### Combine 3pp Content At Your Own Risk

It is often not advisable to combine 3pp content from more than one company for the simple reason that they were not made with each other in mind, regardless of the quality or reputation of both or either publishers. Even if this combination did work by RAW, which it does not, it's not a proposition you should just assume for yourself or your group.